# ASP.NET GridView - some questions about the LinkButton column

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have an LinkButton column in my GridView:

```
<Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField>
         <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:LinkButton runat="server"/>
         </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

let's assume that I need to bound to that GridView a list of some items, where some of them shoud have visible that LinkButton, some not. So that is the question: **how - while bounding/after bound - can I realize that scenario, I mean show LinkButtons (with different CommandArgument) where there are needed ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 options:

1. Handle the RowDataBound event: find the button in the row and set the visible property
2. Bind a property/column in the datasource: `<asp:LinkButton Visible='<%# Bind("Editable") %>'`
3. create a method returning a boolean in the page and use it: `<asp:LinkButton Visible='<%# IsButtonVisible(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID")) %>'`